# Extract URL from lines with specific TLD ReGex

Tags: python, regex

Hi everyone I'm trying to extract URL from a file With the specific ending of ".eu" like .com.

I have this code to get a list of URLs but not with a specific ending. Can anyone improve it to get a specific TLD at the end?

```py
urls = re.findall('https?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+', line).
```

example of lines and expected results.

akijsdijas  adsfaasd asfda https://www.google.eu/asd34a/as3df  asdfs dsf76

a56 64ijas  adsfaasd asfda https://www.facebook.eu/asd34a/as3df  asdfs345 dsf76

fghddijas  adsfaasd asfda https://www.facebook.com/asd34a/as3df  asdfs dsf76

Expected results:

https://www.google.eu

https://www.facebook.eu

Comment: `re.findall(r'https?://\S*\.com\b', line)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'https?://\S*?\.eu\b', line)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o1AqGe/2).

The regex matches:

- `https?://` - `http://` or `https://`
- `\S*?` - any 0+ non-whitespace chars, as few as possible
- `\.eu\b` - a `.eu` followed with a non-word char or end of string.

Comment: I have a problem with it, URLS Like that: "https://account.gov.eu/lagbroker?"https://sso.forms.gov.eu/globaldata/getsequence/gethtmlform.aspx?formtype=mr19ss@moin.gov.eu" gets accepted and I want only:"https://sso.forms.gov.eu"

Comment: @Ethanolle Sorry, no idea what the rule is here.

Comment: sorry I want only "account.gov.eu Before the /

Comment: @Ethanolle If you need the first occurrence only, use `m = re.search(r'https?://\S*?\.eu\b', line)` and then `if  m:` then `print(m.group())`

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
urls = re.findall(r'https?://\S*\.eu\b')
```

Comment: almost I need another improvement because for example ""https://www.sil"" will be accepted as that. maybe you have a completely different method?